# Bubblesort not working on Java, elements are not swapping

Tags: java, bubble-sort

My test code is below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {5,4,1,651,68,7,486,49,3,4,6};
        bubblesort(list);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

    }
    private static void bubblesort(int[] a) {
        int[] list = a;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    list[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output is still:

```
[5, 4, 1, 651, 68, 7, 486, 49, 3, 4, 6]
```

I have made multiple tests like use return or set another variable. But none of my methods works...

Comment: Have you walked through this with a debugger or using print statements to see what's going on?

Comment: I used print statement before and after list[j] = list[j + 1]; for list[j], list[j] did not change

Comment: Look at `list[j] = list[j + 1]; list[j] = temp;` closely.

Answer (score 2):

At a brief look, I think your issue is you are setting **`list[j]`** twice in a row.

You should be setting **`list[j+1] = temp`** in the last line of your **`if`** statement

Answer (score 0):

```
int temp = list[j]; list[j] = list[j + 1]; list[j+1] = temp;
```

You are assigning list[j] value to temp and reassigning  temp value to list[j] , so no change in the output. So no swapping is happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the if block with this one

```
if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) {
   int temp = list[j];
   list[j] = list[j + 1];
   list[j+1] = temp;
}
```